# How do I change the size of my header section?

Tags: iphone, header, titanium, appcelerator

I'd like to change the size of the header of my section and I do not really know what to do.

Can you help me please?
Here is the code:

```
// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({ 

});

var win= Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
    title:'',
    tabBarHidden: true,
    barColor:'black',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var tab= Ti.UI.createTab({
    title:'//////',
    window:win
});

var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: "#FFFEEE"
});

var  section1 = Titanium.UI.createTableViewSection({
    headerTitle:"text long enough "
});

var row1 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:'auto', 
    selectionStyle:Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE
});

var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text:'////// :',
    font:{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold'},
    left: 10
});

var mailtf = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    left: 75,
    right:10,
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_NONE
});

row1.add(label1);
row1.add(mailtf);
section1.add(row1);
....
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a custom header so you need to do a view rather then title. Replace `headerTitle` with `headerView`

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/table_view_api_custom_header.js#L33

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewSection-object#headerView

Comment: I appreciate you're Adorable

I'll try to do that and I will keep you informed of the result

Comment: thank you very much it works nikel I made ​​changes but euhhh there I have the text color the same as that set defaults for header sections

I have to put anything like this color because I like the black color

thank you very much

Comment: @Sabrina I noticed you are new to Stack Overflow and have 5 question wish no selected answer? Just wanted to make sure you understand how the Best Answer feature works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30957/what-answer-should-i-choose-as-the-correct-answer-for-my-question

Answer (score 1):

well, I do not use appcelerator, but it looks like it integrates with native function and delegate calls on objective c.
For setting new header size and personalized views try this 2 methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Comment: Please where do I have to insert this code because it gives me this error when I put it just after the declaration of the section

Comment: this is the error that appears                                      [object TiUITableViewRow] has an auto height value of 0, meaning this view may not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44; //change according to your condition 
}
```

Comment: oula it scares me that way I might add where exactly sorry but I really begins with Appcelerator Thank you